# How to get `str_glue()` to discriminate between an argument and its value?

Tags: dplyr, stringr

Background: `sfun` is a function that mutates `mtcars`. `sfun` has a `cyl` arg which shares the same name as the `cyl` vector in `mtcars`.

Question: When `sfun(cyl = "hp")`, how can I enable `str_glue()` to distinguish the argument (`cyl`) from its value (`hp`)?

```
sfun <- function(mydf, cyl){
  myoutput <- 
    mydf %>% 
    mutate(attempt1 = sprintf("%s shows hp values", !!sym(cyl)))  %>%  ## this works
    mutate(attempt2 = str_glue("{cyl} does not show hp values "))
  return(myoutput)
}
mtcars %>% dplyr::select(cyl, hp) %>% head(5) %>% sfun(cyl="hp")

> mtcars %>% dplyr::select(cyl, hp) %>% head(5) %>% sfun(cyl="hp")
                  cyl  hp            attempt1                   attempt2
Mazda RX4           6 110 110 shows hp values 6 does not show hp values 
Mazda RX4 Wag       6 110 110 shows hp values 6 does not show hp values 
Datsun 710          4  93  93 shows hp values 4 does not show hp values 
Hornet 4 Drive      6 110 110 shows hp values 6 does not show hp values 
Hornet Sportabout   8 175 175 shows hp values 8 does not show hp values 
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to make use of the `.data` and the `.env` pronouns from `rlang`:

- `.data` will pick columns from the data
- `.env` will pick variables from the environment

See e.g. this [blog post](https://tinyheero.github.io/2020/03/01/use-data-env-pronouns-tidyverse.html)

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

sfun <- function(mydf, cyl){
  mydf %>% 
    #mutate(attempt1 = sprintf("%s shows hp values", !!sym(cyl)))  %>%  ## this works
    mutate(attempt2 = str_glue("{.data[[.env$cyl]]} does not show hp values "))
}
mtcars %>% dplyr::select(cyl, hp) %>% 
  head(5) %>% 
  sfun(cyl = "hp")
#>                   cyl  hp                     attempt2
#> Mazda RX4           6 110 110 does not show hp values 
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       6 110 110 does not show hp values 
#> Datsun 710          4  93  93 does not show hp values 
#> Hornet 4 Drive      6 110 110 does not show hp values 
#> Hornet Sportabout   8 175 175 does not show hp values
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to the concept of data masking - very much appreciated! Quick question: is the `.data` pronoun necessary when one could perhaps use `get` - that is, mutate(attempt2 = str_glue("{get(.env$cyl)} does not show hp values "))

Comment: Hi @Yonghao. Good question. In general I avoid using `get`(and also `assign`). But actually it works. And I can't find any reference on why one should avoid it and examples I tried worked. ):